# Why aren’t I getting any new blocks or items in the new snapshots of Minecraft 1.20?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don’t know if they just haven’t been released yet, or if something’s not working correctly.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6wa62K8hM4

Comment: are you on the 22w42a snapshot?

Comment: Jmooroof No, I’m on the 23w04a snapshot, but I also don’t get anything on any of the other snapshots either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @FabianRöling's linked video explains it, even if it's for an older snapshot: To activate the 1.20 features in a newly created world, you'll need to enable the built-in `update_1_20` datapack on world creation.

Comment: @Plagiatus That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @pppery you're right, I've extended it with a little more info and turned it into an answer

Answer (score 4):

They introduced a new system recently on how to get the new content, because they moved to a dual lane system if you will: working on both the next minor (1.19.4) and major (1.20) update at the same time. The features that are enabled by default are only the 1.19.4 features, and the upcoming (and/or for other reasons usually disabled) features are considered **experimental**.

**To enable those experimental features, you'll need to activate a built-in datapack *on world creation*.** They cannot be added retroactively to a world. At the time of writing there are two experimental features accessible that way:

- `update_1_20` which has the 1.20 update features
- `bundle` which adds the bundle that was previously only accessible through commands

You can read their explanation on the [22w42a snapshot article](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-snapshot-22w42a), the first snapshot to use this method, where they explain this new system.